# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider and reading file immediately after its uploaded fails sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have some Web API code that I've assembled from SO posts and other sites. However, the Task stuff is still new to me. I'm trying to copy an uploaded file to a new location, but sometimes (not all the time) I get an exception while trying to copy the file. The exception indicates that the file is in use by another process. It doesn't happen every time, though. I think I need to move the copy operation somewhere else. Here's my code. Any suggestions?

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadroot);
                var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

                    var docConversionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                    var sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(uploadroot, provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName);
                    var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(inboxroot, docConversionId);

                    File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath);

                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Content = new StringContent(docConversionId);
                    //response.Content.Headers.Add("DocumentConversionId", docConversionId);
                    return response;
                });
                return task;
```

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?  What line of code is it occurring on?

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing. Took a little trip over the weekend. I can't copy the file because the file is in use by another process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could be hitting a known issue with trying to read/delete the file immediately after you use ReadAsMultipartAsync.

Following is the bug related to it(you can take a look the resolution information for more details as to why its happening and also a workaround):

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/176

Comment: This looks like it could be the issue I'm dealing with. Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead. Can you provide a workaround please?

Answer (score 1):

Since the original discussion in codeplex is dead, I'm pasting here the original explanation and workaround when the issue was originally closed back in 2013:

> We are closing this issue because the root cause was found to be in
>   framework code. A separate bug has been opened against an external
>   partner team, and this issue will be tracked there.
>
> The changeset:
>   http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/452b8e1dfa40
>
> reverts an attempted fix where we used FileOptions.WriteThrough to
>   ensure it was not a race between the File Cache and FileStream code.
>   But WriteThrough did not address the core bug and caused a performance
>   degradation.
>
> Impact on user code is this: if you upload a file with
>   MultipartFormDataContent and read it on the server using
>   MultiPartDataStreamProvider, the underlying file on the server may not
>   be fully closed after the ReadAsMultipartAsync completes. There is a
>   small window where native code may still be releasing file resources
>   on another thread.
>
> The impact is that a File.Delete or File.OpenRead done on that file
>   immediately after the async read may fail with an IOException ("file
>   is in use by another process"). We observed about 0.3% failure rate in
>   high-load situations. The only known work-around is to put a try/catch
>   around those operations, delay a short time if an IOException occurs,
>   and retry. A 50ms delay generally works, but allowing for multiple
>   retries is recommended. This allows the native thread to finish
>   releasing its resources. In our stress labs, this
>   catch-delay-and-retry algorithm always succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I had this crasy problem and found out that it works with `await` keyword.

```
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
```

without saving a Task in a variable.

Comment: Using async / await for the entire WebAPI project would be good, but, in this case, there was a known bug with the .NET framework code maintaining a lock on the uploaded file. My workaround back then was to do a simple for loop with a retry counter and catch the exception related to a the file lock and then sleep and retry. I don't know if the bug has been fixed (I sure hope it has!). If not, a library like Polly might be a better solution than rolling your own retry loop.

Comment: In my case returned without await Task never ends in some cases. I suppose there is a bug somewhere. With await the file is always released and can be moved or deleted.